# Looking for a tool that finds quickly the duplicates of a known file

Tags: command-line, find, duplicate-files

I have up to now used the tool `fdupes` to find all the duplicates of a file but this doesn't seem to work. I tried to do :

```
fdupes -r ~/Large_directory file_to_find.txt
```

Firstly I have, just after launching this command, the message :

> fdupes: could not chdir to file_to_find.txt.

So, as soon as launched, there is already a mistake in my syntax.

Secondly, the command takes a long time (must build an index which is really very slow).

So I am looking for an alternative tool.

Could anyone indicate me another tool which allows to find fastly all the duplicates of a given file in a given directory and of all its subdirectories?

Any suggestion/help is welcome.

Comment: `fdupes` doesn't take a file as an argument. It just finds duplicates, not from a key file. From `man fdupes`: `fdupes [ options ] DIRECTORY ...`.

Comment: Is `to file_to_find.txt` in the same directory to search?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity : Sorry, I didn't know that fdupes doesn't take a file as argument. Is there a similar command that could find all the duplicates of a given file into a given recursive directory ?

Comment: I'm a little rusty on bash. This is an idea that comes to mind: paste a copy of the file under the directory you are going to search, then apply this command: `fdupes -r -1 ~/Large_directory | grep "file_to_find" | tr -s ' ' '\n'`. This would present you with a list of the files that are duplicates in a column.

Comment: If succesful I can write an answer explaining it.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity . Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, my directory is too large like its subdirectories to use grep on the duplicate(s) file that I want to find. I thought that maybe I could use the `locate` combined with other command to get faster results, I don't know really for the moment, I have to keep looking for. Do you know another specific tool which finds duplicates of a given file from a directory and all its subdirectories ? Regards

Comment: My command is indeed very inefficient, because also looks for *all* dupes, not just the one you want. Anothera pproach is to use a forloop and make the md5sum comparison. You could use also the command `find`, but it's it's purpose, as well as locate. As soon as I can I will suggest a forloop possibility using md5sum.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity Thanks for your remarks

Answer (score 0):

A loop approach:

```
b="$(md5sum file_to_find.txt | cut -d' ' -f1)"

shopt -s globstar

for f in ~/Large_directory/**/*.txt; do 
  [[ "$(md5sum "$f" | cut -d' ' -f1)" = "$b" ]] && realpath "$f"
done
```

Comment: This breaks on filenames with whitespace or globbing characters. `$f` in `md5sum $f` and `realpath $f` should be `"$f"`. The outer quotes, around each enclosing `$(` `)`, suppress word splitting and globbing on the substituted *output* of the commands inside, but don't affect *what* commands are run. The result of parameter expansion of `$f` is still subject to splitting and globbing. I'd edit, but I'm unsure of the intent of `echo "$(realpath $f)"`, which is better as `echo "$(realpath "$f")"`, but presumably even better as just `realpath "$f"`. You may want to use https://www.shellcheck.net.

Comment: @EliahKagan You are right! Thanks. I've been away from bash these last months, I'll edit with your advices.